# Print not printing inside a for cycle

Tags: python, printing

I am looking at a script and I want to insert a print function but Python is giving me Name error:`i` is not defined.

Here is the code

```
for i in xrange(1, len(pts)):

    # if either of the tracked points are None, ignore
    # them
    if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
        continue

    # otherwise, compute the thickness of the line and
    # draw the connecting lines
    #print ('coord: {}'.format(pts[i]))
    thickness = int(np.sqrt(args["buffer"] / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)
    cv2.line(frame, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), thickness)
    #print (pts[i])

# show the frame to our screen
cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

# if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
if key == ord("q"):
    break
```

I just want to print the `pts[i]` and `pts[i-1]` elements inside the cycle but when I try to insert:

```
print (pts[i])
```

I got a Name error on `i`.

What is the mistake?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve].  The code you've posted has about a half-dozen `NameError`s, because we can't see where all those variables are defined.  Also, much of that code is probably unrelated to your error (since `i` doesn't appear anywhere in the second half), so it could be removed.  Finally, please include the _complete_ stack trace...  It will tell us (among other things) exactly where the `NameError` occurred.  See "[ask]" and the links at the bottom of that page for more advice on posting a complete, answerable, useful-to-others question.